# Calling a procedure giving not a valid function or procedure name error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, liquibase

I am getting the following error:
`liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name   Failed SQL: (6576) call D2.R_C('D2','D8')`
I have a file.sql containing the following SQL:

```
call D2.R_C('D2','D8')  
/
```

and this file.sql is included in a changeSet XML of liquibase
D2 is the schema in which the procedure R_C is defined. Not sure why this is giving an error. I tried putting D2 within single quotes too, but still got the same error.

Comment: Does the user you're connecting as have execute permission on that procedure, as it seems to be in a different schema? `call` can throw that error if not, where `execute` or `begin/end` might throw something else (e.g. identifier must be declared). You might also just have the call wrong; please include the procedure specification in your question, as well as whether you granted privileges on it.

Comment: Case sensitive schema or object labels should be enclosed in double-quotes, not single. That said, make sure that the calling schema has execute privileges on the target procedure before doing anything else.

Comment: @AlexPoole ok I will look for the execute permissions. But what I find weird is why doesn't the error directly mentions that this is a permission issue. It throws a generic message. Could it be because since the schema doesn't have permission to execute the procedure, it doesn't actually find that procedure and so it throws an invalid procedure name error? But this could still be confusing in case there is some syntax issue. 
Not sure if it's possible to produce more output in liquibase

Comment: The same reason you get ORA-00942 if you try to a query a table you don't have privileges for. Giving a different error that says "you don't have permission for this thing" tells you - or an attacker - that the thing exists, so it leaks information that could be important. You might be able to tell, for instance, that a DB hosts a particular product by learning that a known table or package exists, making it worth your while to probe further. (Although some people would just say it's because Oracle are bad at helpful error messages *8-)